# how to validate a calendar control in a web page?

Tags: javascript, c#

I need to validate a calendar and that is the only input in my web page. If I gave a wrong input, it should show a pop-up alert but instead I am getting an exception.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Month_Validation() {
        var date= txtSearchDate.Text;
        var month = date.substring(0, 2);
        if (month >12) {
            alert("Please enter a valid date");
        } 
    }
</script>
```

C#:

```
string jsMethodName = "Month_Validation()";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "uniqueKey", jsMethodName, true);
```

An example of the wrong input is "13/7/2019" (mm/dd/yyy) and the I am getting a `System.FormatException` exception at the line `DataTable dt = myTmsBl.GetRoutes_MyViewRoutes(connstr, Convert.ToDateTime(txtSearchDate.Text), Session["UserId"].ToString());`

Comment: What is example o `wrong input`? What exception you are getting? Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: the wrong input which I gave is ''13/7/2019"(mm/dd/yyy) and the I am getting  'System.FormatException'  exception and


I am getting exception at the line 

 "DataTable dt = myTmsBl.GetRoutes_MyViewRoutes(connstr, Convert.ToDateTime(txtSearchDate.Text), Session["UserId"].ToString());"

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/843083/How-to-validate-date-in-asp-net-calendar-control Custom validator is the way for you...

Comment: actually I got pop-up alert for month but I am unable to validate date.
I used the below lines in aspx.cs page to validate month
' ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "PopUp", "alert('Please enter a valid date');", true);
            txtSearchDate.Focus();'

Comment: There is no code you have written for date validation. Without code it won't show the error, right?

Comment: i used the below codes to validate both month and date:
        string selectedDate = txtSearchDate.Text;
        var month = selectedDate.Substring(0, 2);
        var date = selectedDate.Substring(3, 5);
        if( (int.Parse(month) > 12)&& (int.Parse(date)>32))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "PopUp", "alert('Please enter a proper date');", true);
            txtSearchDate.Focus(); return;
        }

Comment: Did try to follow the link I shared about custom validaor? Are you facing any issue in that?

Comment: no..I didn't try the custom validator because I want to check only month and date.. not to compare with future date, month and year